# How to code complicated responsive image grid

Tags: image, css, responsive-design, css-float

I have come across this layout for desktop/tablet and mobile (see images below) i need to complete for a client and i'm finding it impossible to do. I thought of using flex grid, but my client wants it to be IE9 compatible, which stops me using flex as a solution.

Is there a framework out there that's not too heavy that i can implement or can i do this without a framework with just css/3?

Any advice and help would be appreciated, thank you.

[image: image grid layout for desktop and tablet]

[image: image grid layout for mobile]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com) and [Salvattore](http://salvattore.com/) (support IE9+) is known code base's for these stuff and has a lot of built in options, which my below sample haven't, so making your own or use an existing, depends a lot on what you want to do with it.

One can make this version more responsive by adding script and/or also link the section's with one another in slightly different way, though before doing that, one need to know more clearly how the layout should act when screen space shrink.

`position: absolute` version

```css
html, body {margin: 0; height: 100%; }

.container {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header{
  background-color: teal;
  height:30%;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

.wrapper {
  height:80%;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-bottom: 80%;
}

.section {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

.section.nr1 {
  background-color: green;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height:66.6%;
  width:33.3%
}
.section.nr2 {
  background-color: purple;
  left: 33.3%;
  top: 0;
  height:33.3%;
  width:66.6%
}
.section.nr3 {
  background-color: orange;
  left: 33.3%;
  top: 33.3%;
  height:33.3%;
  width:33.3%
}
.section.nr4 {
  background-color: red;
  left: 0;
  top: 66.6%;
  height:33.3%;
  width:66.6%
}
.section.nr5 {
  background-color: gray;
  left: 66.6%;
  top: 33.3%;
  height:66.6%;
  width:33.3%
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  .wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 20%;
  }
  .section.nr1,
  .section.nr2,
  .section.nr3,
  .section.nr4 {
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
  .section.nr5 {
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="section nr1"></div>
        <div class="section nr2"></div>
        <div class="section nr3"></div>
        <div class="section nr4"></div>
        <div class="section nr5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**If** you don't want (or can't) use script, the old `table` can become your friend as it is easy to do this layout with that. Note though, that normally one shouldn't use `table`'s for layout.

The benefit using this is it will grow with its content, which the `position: absolute` version will not.

`table` version (just showing the 5 section layout)

```css
html, body {margin: 0; height: 100% }

.tbl {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border-spacing:0;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
}

.tbl td {
  padding:10px 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align:top
}

.section.nr1 {
  background-color: green;
}
.section.nr2 {
  background-color: purple;
}
.section.nr3 {
  background-color: orange;
}
.section.nr4 {
  background-color: gray;
}
.section.nr5 {
  background-color: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  .tbl {
    width: 90vw;
    height: 90vw;
  }

  .section.nr1,
  .section.nr2,
  .section.nr3,
  .section.nr4 {
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    height: 30vw;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
  .section.nr5 {
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    height: 30vw;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="tbl">
  <tr>
    <td class="section nr1" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td class="section nr2" colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="section nr3"></td>
    <td class="section nr4" rowspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="section nr5" colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: the above examples and solutions are great, however i feel that the image aspect ratios will not be correct. When resizing the screen you can see that the boxes are stretching into a completely different aspect ratio. The specifications are that the images will shrink smaller but maintain same layout and aspect ratio until smaller than tablet size, and then goto 50% width on mobile so that there are two columns

Comment: And also I have just read on the tweets on masonry link you gave me, and it says that IE8/9 support is dropped.

Comment: @HasanKhan Aspect ratio can be controlled by setting a bottom padding. I updated my answer and `padding-bottom: 80%` is set on the wrapper to keep the 5 sections the same. On smaller devices, please update your question on how those 2 columns should look like and I can suggest a solution for that too.

Comment: @HasanKhan Added a second link in my answer to another library that supports IE9 ... and updated the 2:nd sample with viewport units to keep the 5 sections aspect ratio.

Comment: i have added mobile image grid layout

Comment: @HasanKhan I made an update showing one way to do that.

Comment: would the same be possible in table layout too?

Comment: @HasanKhan I updated the table layout to work similar, though recommended is not to use table. If you still do, make sure you test thoroughly in all browsers as messing with table/tr/td like that can give unexpected results